NextJs, AppDir, Mdx and await import: Module Not Found error
I have a NexJs application that uses MDX files for content. I am using @next/mdx for parsing those files. The MDX files display well with no issues.
Here is my next.config.mjs file:
import withMDX from "@next/mdx";

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'mdx']
};

const mdx = withMDX({
    extension: /\.(md|mdx)$/
})

export default mdx(nextConfig);

I want to build a page that collects all MDX files and displays some of the metadata from those files. (Like a list of posts that shows titles and some other info)
I have a method that returns the list of MDX files and attempts to await import each MDX file in order to read the metadata. The await import line consistently fails with MODULE_NOT_FOUND error.
Here is my method:
export async function getFiction() {
    const files = await fs.readdir('./src/app/fiction', {withFileTypes: true})
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files, null, 2))
    const fileDirs = files.filter(p=>p.isDirectory())

    const fileMetadata: any[] = []

    for (const fileDir of fileDirs) {
        try {
            const pagePath = `./src/app/fiction/${fileDir.name}/page.mdx`
            const page = await import(pagePath);
            fileMetadata.push( page.metadata)
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    }

    fileMetadata.sort((a,b) => +new Date(b.publishDate) - +new Date(a.publishDate))

    return fileMetadata
}

The error is on the await import line. I have tried every possible permutation of the pagePath variable, including:

./src/app/fiction/${fileDir.name}/page.mdx
./app/fiction/${fileDir.name}/page.mdx
./fiction/${fileDir.name}/page.mdx
./app/fiction/${fileDir.name}
./src/app/fiction/${fileDir.name}

and every time it is a module not found error:
{
  "code": "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
  "message": "Cannot find module '/fiction/my-file-name.mdx'"
}

stacktrace:
Error: Cannot find module '/fiction/my-file-name'
    at a:\path\.next\server\app\fiction\page.js:25:11
    at async getFiction (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/server-methods/content-helpers.ts:41:26)
    at async FictionListPage (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/fiction/page.tsx:11:21)       

